# Haskell List Comprehension and space leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, list-comprehension, monads, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to figure out how recursion combined with List Comprehension/Monadic operations cause space leaks.

I have a small test program:

```
module Main where
permute :: [a] -> Integer -> [[a]]
permute _ 0 = [[]]
permute xs' n = [x:xs | x <- xs', xs <- permute xs' (n-1)]
chars1 = ['0'..'9']
main = do
  putStrLn $ (permute chars1 10000)!!100000000 -- Leaks
  print $ [1..]!!100000000 -- Does not leak
```

Now, my understanding is that the function `permute` can be expanded as

```
xs' >>= \x -> (permute xs' (n-1) >>= \xs -> (x:xs))
```

So lots of `(permute xs' n)` will be stacked before a result can be retrieved. Am I understanding correctly? If so, what can I do to make sure the function does not leak?

Comment: Yes, this code looks fishy. What's `permute` supposed to do, exactly?

Comment: A list of all possible length-n sequences chosen from elements of `xs'`. For example, `permute "123" 2` should give `["11","12","13","21","22","23","31","32","33"]`

Answer (score 2):

This code is a little bit weird because `permute` doesn't actually.. well.. permute things but assuming that it's what you intended it actually performs in much the same way as your `[0..] !! 10000` example, it's just that computing the 10000th selection is a lot more work in your code!

The important thing is that your code *is* lazy, we can easily compute the 1st element of `permute [0..] 10` even though there are clearly infinitely many of them.

What you might be thinking of though is that when you actually run this it takes a really long time to produce *any* output even if you might hope that it would produce the 1st character... wait a bit.. produce the second character.. wait a bit.. and so on. This is not really a "leak" in the Haskell sense and cannot be avoided in this scenario. Youre list is essentially constructed with

```
map ('0':) (permute chars (n - 1)) ++ ... ++ map ('9':) (permute chars (n - 1))
```

The issue is that in order to know the first character, you need to figure out which "block" you'll be selecting from, which involves computing the length of the block, which involves evaluating `permute chars (n - 1)` fully. So what'll happen is you'll force each recursive call in turn until you have enough elements in the resulting list to evaluate the call to `!!`. This is not unexpected though. You can however significantly speed up this code with one fairly simple trick: reverse the `x` and `xs` in the list comprehension.

```
permute :: [a] -> Integer -> [[a]]
permute _ 0 = [[]]
permute xs' n = [x:xs | xs <- permute xs' (n-1), x <- xs']
```

Do note that the increased sharing could in theory lead to increased memory usage (something may not be GCed as soon in this version) but I'm unable to come up with a not-absurdly-contrived program which does this.

Comment: Oh wow, it actually evaluates... But why does order matter? I don't quite understand this point

Comment: I think the expansion is `permute xs' (n-1) >>= \xs->(xs'>>=\x->(x:xs))`, then the recursive call is done first... but why doesn't this one blow up the memory?

Comment: BTW, I don't really find a mathematical name for this operation, so... words from alphabet, maybe?